# Swapping words with sed

Tags: text-processing, sed

I need help with `sed`, actually with Linux regular expressions:
I need to change two parameters between parentheses, for instance, if the line is

```
 mysqli_select_db($par1, $par2)<br/>
```

I need to change it to

```
 mysqli_select_db($par2, $par1)<br/>
```

I need something generic, they aren't always going to be `par1` and `par2`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A more pedantic approach with `sed`:

```
sed 's/\(mysqli_select_db(\)\([^,]*\)\(,[[:space:]]*\)\([^)]*\))/\1\4\3\2)/g' file
```

- `s/` substitute
- `\(` start capturing group 1
- `mysqli_select_db(` match literal string
- `\)` end capturing group 1
- `\(` start capturing group 2
- `[^,]*` match any non-comma characters
- `\)` end capturing group 2
- `\(` start capturing group 3
- `,[[:space:]]*` match comma and optional space characters
- `\)` end capturing group 3
- `\(` start capturing group 4
- `[^)]*` match any non-`)` characters
- `\)` end capturing group 4
- `)` closing `)` of command
- `/\1\4\3\2)/g` replace with capturing groups 1, 4, 3, 2 and closing `)`

Comment: Ok, you're a genius.
That was it, what I needed.
Thanks man.

Answer (score 2):

You  can use:

```
sed -E 's/(.*\()(.*), (.*)(\).*)/\1\3, \2\4/g' file_name
```

e.g.

```
echo 'mysqli_select_db($par1, $par2)<br/>' | sed -E 's/(.*\()(.*), (.*)(\).*)/\1\3, \2\4/g'
```

will give output as:

```
mysqli_select_db($par2, $par1)<br/>
```

Comment: Yes, in this case, ok.
But I want something generic.
Those words between parenthesis can be anything and I have to put on a script to change dozens os files.

Comment: @CarlosParisotto it will always work as long as you don't remove braces. This command doesn't depends on `<br/>`. The only condition is that there should be two values inside the braces.

Comment: (1) Trivially, this assumes that there is only one pair of parentheses.  More precisely, if there are multiple pairs of parentheses, this operates on the last one.  (2) Unlike the accepted answer, this allows any function name before the `(`.  (The question does not say whether `mysqli_select_db` should be hardcoded.)  (3) Perhaps more importantly, this assumes that there is exactly one space after the comma.  (The question does not say whether this should be variable.) … … … … … … … … … … … … That said, this seems to be as good as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is a crude example based on your example above. You can of course adapt.

The key is to identify the two groups you want to invert and use them in the second part.

```
$ echo 'mysqli_select_db($par1, $par2)<br/>' | sed 's/mysqli_select_db(\(.*\), \(.*\))/mysqli_select_db(\2, \1)/'
```

results in

```
mysqli_select_db($par2, $par1)<br/>
```

Comment: Except that I don't have a common identification. Those words between parenthesis can be anything and I have to put on a script to change dozens os files.